# Limit length of list python

Tags: python

I don't know if this question was asked somewhere, but I did not find it.

I'm appending elements to a list.

```
thr_core0 +=[fpid[thread]]
```

this happens periodically..
At time 0:

thr_core0 [9886, 9890]

At time1:

thr_core0 [9886, 9890, 9886, 9890]

Is it possible to limit the length of the list to 2.

I know it is possible using `deque`. but is it possible also using `lists`.

using `deque`, we do it like this:

```
thr_core0 += [deque([0]*2,maxlen=2)]
```

These are the keywords I searched for on google: `limit` `list` `length` `python`

Comment: Technically yes - but you don't want to - that's what `deque` is for...

Comment: your usage of `deque` seems incorrect. You probably want: `thr_core0 = deque([0]*2, maxlen=2); thr_core2.append(9886); ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not pretty, but you could slice it:

```
thr_core0 = (thr_core0 + [fpid[thread]])[:2]
```

This will always make sure `the_core0` has at most two elements.

Comment: Okay. I will use deque in that case. But, a tick mark for this answer is necessary.

Comment: @rnish: to keep the last two values instead of the first two values: `L = L[-2:]`